# Unable to Call System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.WSManConnectionInfo

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I need to achieve this using **.Net-3.5**

I have referenced the required DLLs in my project:

[[image]]

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
```

But whenever I try using `WSManConnectionInfo`, for example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/773685/Enable-Remote-PowerShell-Execution-in-Csharp):

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.ComputerName = machineAddress;
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{ 
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.AddScript("Get-Service"); 
    var results = ps.Invoke();
    // Do something with result ... 
}  
runspace.Close();
```

I get a "type could not be found" error:

`The type or namespace 'WSManConnectionInfo' could not be foun (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)`

I am trying to remote into a PowerShell session on our server (from an app running locally on the client machine), which can then query which processes are running in that person's session.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.wsmanconnectioninfo(v=vs.85).aspx) all I need is the `System.Management.Automation` namespace, and I couldn't see any mention of framework version limitations. Am I being really stupid here or does Microsoft just have the worst documentation in the universe?

Comment: Microsoft.CSharp with an exclamation, interesting...

Comment: @Gusman Very interesting! When I right-click on it one option says `Add Fake Assembly` I am using .NET-3.5 btw

Comment: that's because the file is not found and vs asks you if you want to create a fake assembly. Try to correct first that error.

Comment: @Gusman Okay I fixed that error and uploading new screenshot now, but I still can't call WSManConnectionInfo!

Comment: PS I resolved this by just creating a brand new project!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for [here](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2015/03/the-type-or-namespace-name-automation-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-management.html).

Basically, I had to change my reference from

`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll`

to

`C:\Program Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll`

Comment: One difference could be that one dll targets 64bit and one targets x86/32bit. Its possible your project was set to "x86" and required the x86 (32bit) version of the dll to load, Unlikely though, usually you'll get a some "platform" exception when that happens.